# need of condition to print helloworld

Tags: c

I want to print both Hello and world.
so what should be the "condition" so that the following code snippet prints HelloWorld

```
if "condition"
printf ("Hello");
else
printf("World");
```

Comment: printf("Hello"); printf("World");

Comment: int i; for (i=0; i<2; ++i) { if (i==0) printf("Hello"); else printf("World"); } /* do not hire me because I overcomplicate things! */

Comment: Maybe some background would help... what are you trying to do that makes you feel you need to hit both an `if` and the `else` condition?

Comment: I'm glad George Boole does not have to read this...

Comment: Sheesh, it's easily possible without changing the structure. `if (!printf("Hello")) printf("Hello"); else printf("World");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way... `if`/`else` is one or the other. Not both.

If you want to do more than one thing conditionally it has to be something like:

```
int i =2;
if (i == 2)
    printf("Hello");
if (i > 0)
    printf("World");
```

These are concurrent `if`s and the same variable will be evaluated each time you hit one. In this case you'll get `HelloWorld` because both conditions are true.

Answer (score 1):

Following your question you don't need the condition at all.

Answer (score 1):

*Not possible*. It's either `if` or `else`.

But **hold on**,  The evil [`goto`](http://xkcd.com/292/) wants to say something :

```
//sg
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

    if(1)
    {
    printf("Hello");
    goto evil;
    }
    else
    {
    evil:
    printf(" World");
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its only going to do both if you call it twice and flip the condition for the second call.

Comment: no i don't want to call it twice

Comment: Then just do printf("Hello World"); ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
switch (condition) {
    case 0: 
    case 1:
        printf("Hello");
        printf("World");
        break;
}
```

This will do "HelloWorld" where condition is 0 or 1.  If/else handles mutually exclusive events (handles one case OR another, but never both).